# need user to be able to input up to three letters at a time for python turtle to draw

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have the code all worked out to be able to input one letter at a time but for some reason cant figure out how to make it so the user can input up to three letters for turtle to draw. this is my code so far. any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance

```
import turtle
velcro = turtle.Turtle()
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('pink')
velcro.color("purple", "blue")
velcro.color()
('purple', 'blue')
velcro.pensize("12")

def color_purple():
  velcro.color ('purple')
def color_blue():
  velcro.color('blue')
def color_black():
  velcro.color ('black')


velcroColor = turtle.textinput("pick a color", "please chose from the colors purple, blue or black, to draw in")
if (velcroColor == 'purple'):
  color_purple()
elif (velcroColor == 'blue'):
  color_blue()
elif (velcroColor == 'black'):
  color_black()


def letter_A():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.right(180)
  velcro.forward(75)
  velcro.left(90)                             
  velcro.forward(150)                        

def letter_B():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(80)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(80)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(80)
  velcro.right(180)
  velcro.forward(95)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(80)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(93)

def letter_C():
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(150)

def letter_D():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.right(98)
  velcro.forward(180)
  velcro.right(85)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.right(96)
  velcro.forward(172)

def letter_E():
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(155)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(155)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(155)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(155)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(125)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(150)

def letter_F():
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.right(180)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(95)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(125)


def letter_G():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(155)
  velcro.right(180)
  velcro.forward(155)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(225)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(175)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(80)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(80)


def letter_H():
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(175)
  velcro.right(180)
  velcro.forward(300)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(125)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(125)
  velcro.right(180)
  velcro.forward(300)


def letter_I():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(100)
  velcro.right(180)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.right(180)
  velcro.forward(100)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(100)
  velcro.right(180)
  velcro.forward(200)

def letter_J():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(100)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(100)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(100)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(95)

def letter_K():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(100)
  velcro.left(145)
  velcro.forward(100)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(100)
  velcro.left(85)
  velcro.forward(150)

def letter_L():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(300)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(200)

def letter_M():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.right(140)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.left(100)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.right(140)
  velcro.forward(250)

def letter_N():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.right(140)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.left(140)
  velcro.forward(200)

def letter_O():
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(100)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(100)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(250)

def letter_P():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(95)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(95)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(95)

def letter_Q():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.left(140)
  velcro.forward(50)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(100)

def letter_R():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(100)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(115)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(100)
  velcro.left(135)
  velcro.forward(180)

def letter_S():
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(150)

def letter_T():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(50)
  velcro.right(180)
  velcro.forward(100)

def letter_U():
  velcro.left(90)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.right(90)
  velcro.forward(200)

def letter_V():
  velcro.left(115)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(250)
  velcro.left(120)
  velcro.forward(250)

def letter_W():
  velcro.left(270)
  velcro.forward(275)
  velcro.right(140)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.left(100)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.right(140)
  velcro.forward(275)

def letter_X():
  velcro.left(140)
  velcro.forward(300)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.right(270)
  velcro.forward(150)
  velcro.right(180)
  velcro.forward(300)

def letter_Y():
  velcro.left(140)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.right(275)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.left(180)
  velcro.forward(200)
  velcro.left(45)
  velcro.forward(250)

def letter_Z():
  velcro.forward(225)
  velcro.left(140)
  velcro.forward(300)
  velcro.right(140)
  velcro.forward(225)



velcroLetter = turtle.textinput("Turtle alphabet", "please enter a capital letter from A-Z to draw:")
if (velcroLetter == 'a' or velcroLetter == 'A'):
   letter_A()
elif (velcroLetter == 'b' or velcroLetter == 'B'):
   letter_B()
elif (velcroLetter == 'c' or velcroLetter == 'C'):
   letter_C()
elif (velcroLetter == 'd' or velcroLetter == 'D'):
   letter_D()
elif (velcroLetter == 'e' or velcroLetter == 'E'):
   letter_E()
elif (velcroLetter == 'f' or velcroLetter == 'F'):
   letter_F()
elif (velcroLetter == 'g' or velcroLetter == 'G'):
   letter_G()
elif (velcroLetter == 'h' or velcroLetter == 'H'):
   letter_H()
elif (velcroLetter == 'i' or velcroLetter == 'I'):
   letter_I()
elif (velcroLetter == 'j' or velcroLetter == 'J'):
   letter_J()
elif (velcroLetter == 'k' or velcroLetter == 'K'):
   letter_K()
elif (velcroLetter == 'l' or velcroLetter == 'L'):
   letter_L()
elif (velcroLetter == 'm' or velcroLetter == 'M'):
   letter_M()
elif (velcroLetter == 'n' or velcroLetter == 'N'):
   letter_N()
elif (velcroLetter == 'o' or velcroLetter == 'O'):
   letter_O()
elif (velcroLetter == 'p' or velcroLetter == 'P'):
   letter_P()
elif (velcroLetter == 'q' or velcroLetter == 'Q'):
   letter_Q()
elif (velcroLetter == 'r' or velcroLetter == 'R'):
   letter_R()
elif (velcroLetter == 's' or velcroLetter == 'S'):
   letter_S()
elif (velcroLetter == 't' or velcroLetter == 'T'):
   letter_T()
elif (velcroLetter == 'u' or velcroLetter == 'U'):
   letter_U()
elif (velcroLetter == 'v' or velcroLetter == 'V'):
   letter_V()
elif (velcroLetter == 'w' or velcroLetter == 'W'):
   letter_W()
elif (velcroLetter == 'x' or velcroLetter == 'X'):
   letter_X()
elif (velcroLetter == 'y' or velcroLetter == 'Y'):
   letter_Y()
elif (velcroLetter == 'z' or velcroLetter == 'Z'):
   letter_Z()


turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on, `turtle.textinput()` allows me to type as many letters as I want and even non-letter characters.

Comment: i can enter as many letters as i want, turtle just does not draw them

Answer (score 0):

Since your letters print relative to the origin (0, 0), the trick is to divide the screen into portions (say thirds) and for each letter, move to the center of the appropriate portion before drawing the letter.

I've reworked your code below to do the above (for up to three letters) and simplify some of your logic.  The letter functions themselves are unchanged so I left out the bulk of them below, just splice in your original code there:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1200, 600
SCREEN_MARGIN = 0.1 * SCREEN_WIDTH
MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS = 3
CHARACTER_WIDTH = (SCREEN_WIDTH - (2 * SCREEN_MARGIN)) / MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS
COLORS = ['purple', 'blue', 'black']

velcro = Turtle()
screen = Screen()

def letter_A():
    velcro.left(90)
    velcro.forward(150)
    velcro.right(90)
    velcro.forward(150)
    velcro.right(90)
    velcro.forward(150)
    velcro.right(180)
    velcro.forward(75)
    velcro.left(90)
    velcro.forward(150)

# ...

def letter_Z():
    velcro.forward(225)
    velcro.left(140)
    velcro.forward(300)
    velcro.right(140)
    velcro.forward(225)

letter_lookup = {
    'A': letter_A,
    'B': letter_B,
    'C': letter_C,
    'D': letter_D,
    'E': letter_E,
    'F': letter_F,
    'G': letter_G,
    'H': letter_H,
    'I': letter_I,
    'J': letter_J,
    'K': letter_K,
    'L': letter_L,
    'M': letter_M,
    'N': letter_N,
    'O': letter_O,
    'P': letter_P,
    'Q': letter_Q,
    'R': letter_R,
    'S': letter_S,
    'T': letter_T,
    'U': letter_U,
    'V': letter_V,
    'W': letter_W,
    'X': letter_X,
    'Y': letter_Y,
    'Z': letter_Z,
}

screen.setup(width=SCREEN_WIDTH, height=SCREEN_HEIGHT)

screen.bgcolor('pink')
velcro.color("purple", "blue")
velcro.pensize("12")

color_string = ", ".join(COLORS[:-1]) + " or " + COLORS[-1]

velcroColor = screen.textinput("Pick a Color", "Please chose from the colors " + color_string + ", to draw with")

if (velcroColor in COLORS):
    velcro.color(velcroColor)

velcroLetters = screen.textinput("Turtle alphabet", "Please enter up to 3 letters from A-Z to draw:")[:MAXIMUM_CHARACTERS]

center_x = CHARACTER_WIDTH * (len(velcroLetters) - 1) / -2

for letter in velcroLetters:
    velcro.penup()
    velcro.home()
    velcro.goto(center_x, 0)
    velcro.pendown()
    letter_lookup[letter.upper()]()

    center_x += CHARACTER_WIDTH

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's because you're typing multiple letters at once. Your program then checks if e. g. "ABC" matches "A". Try entering single letters.